# At which point can I add custom information into userDetails?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I want to store additional information in my custom "userDetail"-object, but I am not sure when I want to add the information into the object. It needs to be accessible for every method after the login happened (JWT-Token login) via `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getInformation()`
I thought about setting it in my custom AuthenticationController around the time the token is generated, but this is difficult due to the act that the referenced type at that point is userDetails, not customUserDetails:

```
UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
//TODO setInformation
String token = this.tokenUtils.generateToken(userDetails);
```

What is the best point in the authentication/authorization process to add such information, and how would I best do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, the best point in time to populate the user object with custom data seems to be the constructor of your customized implementation of the UserDetails interface, at the same time Authorities and other data is set for the User object. For example:

```
    public SpringSecurityUser(Long id, String username, String password, String email, Date lastPasswordReset,
                          Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setUsername(username);
    this.setPassword(password);
    this.setEmail(email);
    this.setLastPasswordReset(lastPasswordReset);
    this.setAuthorities(authorities);
    this.setMyInfo(Information);
    }
```

This was initially a problem for me, because the method setting the information was doing so based on the logged in Principal, which is not possible because at that time of the login process, the Principal is being created.